# How to use enums for class functions

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums

I'm working on a project and I have created a class to handle the json response to convert it to modal class and change it back to json request with updated data if needed.

Here in the class I'm getting and saving values from and into dictionary. I need to create an enum for the dictionary keys so that there should be less chance for error for complex key formats.

I even tried using like

```
enum Fields {
   case Name
   case Email
}
```

but Fields.Email return Fields object

if I use a protocol of a variable like

```
protocol someProtocol {
      var name: String { get }
}

extension someProtocol {
     var name:String {
         return String(describing: self)
     }
}
```

and then extend the `enum Fields:someProtocol`
then I can use it like `Fields.name.name or Fields.email.name`

But My client will not approve this I want to create an enum so that I can access the string directly like for name I want key "Name" and I should get it liek "Fields.name" or ".name"

So here I have two objectives

- first it that I need to create something that can be accessed through class function
- second it should be common so that I can use it with multiple classes
- third I can access it with less operators

—

```
class PersonService {
    class Update {
        var name = ""
        var email = ""
        var personId = 0

        func createDataFrom(dic:[AnyHashable : Any]) -> Update {
            let update = Update()

            update.name = dictionary["Name"]
            update.email = dictionary["Email"]
            update.personId = dictionary["Id"]

            return update
        }

        func createDataTo() -> [AnyHashable:Any] {
            var ret = [AnyHashable : Any]()

            ret["Name"] = name
            ret["Email"] = email
            ret["Id"] = personId

            return ret
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know all the keys of your "dictionary" why don't you just use `Codable` and parse it to some type?

Comment: Codable has some drawbacks thats why drop that idea

Comment: What drawbacks?

Comment: +vs
1  Doesn’t need manual serialization
-ve's
1  Crashes if property is missing
2  Doesn’t work with base classes
3  Requires variables names to match

Comment: 1. If property may be missing you should declare variable optional. 2. Which classes? 3. You can declare nested `CodingKey` enum for your type to map all the names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
enum Fields: String {
   case Name = "Name"
   case Email = "Email"
}
```

```
Print(Fields.Name.rawValue)
result: "Name"
```

**Or**

```
struct Constants {
    static let name = "Name"
    static let email = "Email"
}
```

```
print(Constants.name)
result: "Name"
```

Comment: In this case I have to defined a kewy two times like Name and ahve to use extra ,rawValue key word. is not there any way to make it much shorter ?

Comment: With an enum, no, because you have to use a string in your dictionary.

You can set a struct with your constants, i updated the example.